# Recovering odt file using scalpel

Tags: ubuntu

Right now, I was working with an odt file which vanished from its folder (don't ask me why).

```
~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4       91317328  72333904  14321716  84% /
none                   4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             1955444         4   1955440   1% /dev
tmpfs             393112      1212    391900   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1965552       276   1965276   1% /run/shm
none              102400        48    102352   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2      393654268 262304760 131349508  67% /media/lucas/F2DC2A2CDC29EC13

~$ mkdir ~/Desktop/scalpel_recovered_files/

~$ sudo scalpel /dev/sda4 -b -o ~/Desktop/scalpel_recovered_files/
Scalpel version 1.60
Written by Golden G. Richard III, based on Foremost 0.69.
ERROR: You have attempted to use a non-empty output directory. In order
       to maintain forensic soundness, this is not allowed.
Aborting.

~$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've managed to restore the file :) !!!!

For those interested step by step:

1.sudo apt-get install scalpel

2.You may have to modify the scalpel.conf file depending on the file extension you need to recover. So in my case I added to end of the file (I used nano to edit the file):

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# OPENOFFICE FILES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
    odt y   20000000    PK????????????????????????????mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.textPK META-INF/manifest.xmlPK????????????????????
    ods y   10000000    PK????????????????????????????mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheetPK  META-INF/manifest.xmlPK????????????????????
    odp y   10000000    PK????????????????????????????mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentationPK META-INF/manifest.xmlPK????????????????????
#    odg y   10000000    PK????????????????????????????mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphicsPK META-INF/manifest.xmlPK????????????????????
#    odc y   10000000    PK????????????????????????????mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chartPK    META-INF/manifest.xmlPK????????????????????
#    odf y   10000000    PK????????????????????????????mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formulaPK  META-INF/manifest.xmlPK????????????????????
#    odi y   10000000    PK????????????????????????????mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.imagePK    META-INF/manifest.xmlPK????????????????????
#    odm y   10000000    PK????????????????????????????mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-masterPK  META-INF/manifest.xmlPK????????????????????
#    sxw y   10000000    PK????????????????????????????mimetypeapplication/vnd.sun.xml.writerPK  META-INF/manifest.xmlPK????????????????????
```

3.My Ubuntu is installed on /dev/sda4 partition:
sudo scalpel /dev/sda4 -b -o ~/Desktop/scalpel_recovered_files/

4.Now access ~/Desktop/scalpel_recovered_files/ (I had to use sudo su)

5.You will see the audit.txt file and another bunch of folders were scalpel has carved whatever files he found during the scan.

```
root@K55VD:/home/lucas/Desktop/scalpel_recovered_files# dir
audit.txt  odp-2-0  ods-1-0  odt-0-0
```

6.So I opened my odt-0-0 and started browsing the odt files. They are numbered according to the most recent. After browsing the first 5 odt files I've found the missing file.